# Equality almost everywhere and in $L^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lp-spaces, periodic-functions

Suppose that I have a set of null (Lebesgue) measure $N\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N,\qquad \lim_{p\to + \infty} \sum_{i=1}^p b_n f_n(t) \text{ exists and belongs to } \mathbb{R},$$
where $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n$ are in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $T$-periodic functions. We define a function $f$ such that for $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N$, 
$$f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} b_n f_n(t).$$

Now take a $T$-periodic function $g\in L^2_{\text{loc}}$ such that $g= f$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$. Setting $G = g(T \cdot) \in L^2(]0,1[)$, do we have 
$$\left(\left(  g= f\text{ almost everywhere in }\mathbb{R} \right) \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad G = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} b_n f_n(T \cdot) \text{ in } L^2(]0,1[) \right) ? $$

For me, we have
$$ \begin{array}{cl}
 & \left(  g= f\text{ almost everywhere in }\mathbb{R} \right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & \left(  g= f\text{ almost everywhere in } [0,T] \right)\\
\Leftrightarrow & \left(  G= \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} b_n f_n(T \cdot)\text{ almost everywhere in }[0,1] \right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & \left( G = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} b_n f_n(T \cdot) \text{ in } L^2(]0,1[) \right) \\
\end{array}
$$
But I might be missing something. In particular, is it true that if $G = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} b_n f_n(T \cdot)$ in $L^2(]0,1[)$ then there exits a set of null (Lebesgue) measure $N\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N,\qquad \lim_{p\to + \infty} \sum_{i=1}^p b_n f_n(T t) \text{ exists and belongs to } \mathbb{R} ?$$

Comment: Are you asking: If $F=0 \ \ (L^2)$ then $F = 0 \ \ (\text{a.e.})$?

Comment: No, my problem is about convergence of the series involved here.

Comment: if $G$ is in $L^2$ then it is defined and finite almost everywhere, hence the series converge almost eveywhere.

Comment: But if $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} b_n f_n(T \cdot)$ in $L^2(]0,1[)$ (which means that the series of functions converges in $L^2$), one can only prove that the series of functions converges a.e up to a subsequence, right?

Comment: Knowing $G$ (regardless of it's representation as a series) is in $L^2$ implies it is defined and finite almost everywhere. Now since $G = \sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i$ we realize that for almost every $x$ the series converges.